# iota.c lib sending transaction returns cclient_res_error with status 400

Tags: transaction

I am currently having troubles with some example code I found on github regarding the `iota.c` library (example code in README file). However I am not able to send a valid transaction using `iota_client_send_transfer()` function as it returns a `CCLIENT_RES_ERROR` and a http status 400. I just can't get my head around this issue.

I use the following definitions:

```
#define CONFIG_IRI_NODE_URI "nodes.thetangle.org"
#define CONFIG_IRI_NODE_PORT 443
#define TIP_SELECTION_DEPTH 3
#define MINIMUM_WEIGHT_MAGNITUDE 14
#define DEPTH 3
#define SECURITY_LEVEL 2
```

My example code looks like this:

```
m_service = iota_client_core_init(CONFIG_IRI_NODE_URI, CONFIG_IRI_NODE_PORT,ROOT_CA1_PEM);
retcode_t retcode = RC_OK;
char message[] = "Hello World";

bundle_transactions_t *bundle = nullptr;
bundle_transactions_new(&bundle);

transfer_array_t *transfers = transfer_array_new();
transfer_t tf = {};

flex_trits_from_trytes(tf.address, NUM_TRITS_ADDRESS,ADDRESS,NUM_TRYTES_ADDRESS, NUM_TRYTES_ADDRESS);
    
retcode = transfer_message_set_string(&tf,message);
transfer_array_add(transfers,&tf);
retcode = iota_client_send_transfer(
      m_service, NULL, SECURITY_LEVEL, DEPTH,
      MINIMUM_WEIGHT_MAGNITUDE, false, transfers, NULL, NULL, NULL, bundle);
```

This is the output of `iota_client_send_transfer`:

```
[parser_on_headers_complete:239] status=400, offset=0, nread=0
```

I've tried to change the definitions, but that didn't help. Also the tutorials on the official iota page seem to be out of date. Has anybody a clue of what the problem might be?

I would really appreciate your help! Thanks in advance.

edit: added iota.c to title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those example are outdated, you can try these examples here:

https://github.com/iotaledger/iota.c/tree/master/cclient/api/examples